# RAID 0 disk failure,how much Recovery chances?

Tags: raid

I had a RAID 0 with 8 disks. One of the disks failed. Is there any possibility to recover data from the remaining 7 disks?

Answer (score 1):

RAID level 0 just stripes the data, meaning consecutive blocks are on different disks. If one fails, then that part of the data is gone. There is no parity or recovery data stored.

Theoretically if some of the files were very small, they might reside on the other 7 disks entirely, but without the file system structure data you won't know where they are.

So there is in reality no way to recover data using only the remaining disks, only possibility is to get the data from the failed disk to make it whole.

Comment: if i install linux(OS) on new disk  when replacement of fail disk then mount the remain disk is there any chance of recovery with recovery software??

Comment: @TayyabFayyaz Most likely you won't be able to mount them since the file system won't be recognized. If it was software RAID then the stack won't be consistent and won't come up. You can try recovery software but since 1/8 of the data is gone, it's quite unlikely anything useful would come up. Only chance is if the file system structures would be all there (won't be since they usually are contiguous, so parts are missing) and the data would be stored non-consecutively magically on the remaining disks, or the files are small and entirely on the 7 disks. So the chances are very small.

Comment: yes i'm understand Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: is there any change to recover data from failure disk ?

Comment: @TayyabFayyaz Yes, depending on how it failed. If it's an electrical failure on the disk, changing the board may help. If it's a worse disk error, data recovery companies may be able to get almost all of the data out of it, but at a cost.